# strcmp returning true when comparing two char pointer values in c

Tags: c, linux, unix

I am trying to compare the 2 passwords for authentication but it is returning true even if I have wrongly input the password. I have tried other ways but it is not working. Can you help?

```
void registerUser() 
{
 char userName[32];





printf("Maximum length for username is 32 characters long\n");
printf("Enter username: ");
scanf("%s",userName);


char *passwordFirst = getpass("Enter new UNIX password: ");


char *passwordSecond = getpass("Retype new UNIX Password: ");



if (strcmp(passwordFirst,passwordSecond)==0)
{
    printf("GOOD");
}

else
{

    printf("Sorry, passwords do not match\n");
    printf("passwd: Authentication token manipulation error\n");
    printf("passwd: password unchanged\n");

}
```

Comment: @FiddlingBits how do i fix it?

Comment: @FiddlingBits getpass is already inbuilt. I have used it to not display the password when the user types

Comment: Sorry, didn't know that.

Comment: Completely ignoring the blatant warning, "This function is obsolete.  Do not use it.", read the man page further. Esp the part that says, "The function getpass() returns a pointer to a static buffer..."

Answer (score 5):

The `getpass` function returns a pointer to a static buffer.  This means that `passwordFirst` and `passwordSecond` point to the same place.

You need to make a copy of the password returned from this function.

```
char *passwordFirst = strdup(getpass("Enter new UNIX password: "));
char *passwordSecond = strdup(getpass("Retype new UNIX Password: "));
```

Don't forget to `free` the memory returned from `strdup`.

Comment: How do i free it?

Comment: @Ox12345 `free(passwordFirst)` and `free(passwordSecond)` when you're done using them.

Comment: @Ox12345 Check the documentation of `strdup`. It will tell you to use `free`, just as you would with a `malloc`.

Comment: @WhozCraig yes I will

Answer (score 1):

You should copy the string pointed to by `getpass` when it returns, into a local buffer. Otherwise, each pointer that you assign will point to the *same* internal buffer that `getpass` uses:

```c
char passwordFirst[33] = ""; // Initialise all chars to zero...
strncpy(passwordFirst, getpass("Enter new UNIX password: "), 32);
char passwordSecond[33] = "";// ... so "strncpy" will be safe if >32 chars given
strncpy(passwordSecond, getpass("Retype new UNIX Password: "), 32);

if (strcmp(passwordFirst, passwordSecond)==0)
{
    printf("GOOD");
}
// ...
```